# How to set _auth for a scoped registry in .npmrc?

Tags: node.js, authentication, npm, nexus, npm-publish

I am wondering how to configure the `.npmrc` file so that I can have a default registry and a different scoped registry with authentication.

I am using Nexus for the private repository and I am not sure how to set authentication for the scoped registry, only the default registry.

For example my `~/.npmrc` file is:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@test-scope:registry=http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/
email=test@user.com
_auth="…"
```

If I do `npm publish` for a package scoped to `test-scope`, I get an authentication error.

AFAIK, the `_auth` only applies to the `registry=...` section. Is there a way of specifying an auth key for the `@test-scope:registry=...` section?

Thanks,

Comment: if I understood your scenario correctly, you are asking for setting two different auth for your `npm-private` registry and `npm-open` registry individually.

Comment: not necessarily `npm-open`, just `npm-private` at this stage, although it would be interesting to know how they can both have auth. (I do realise the example has an `_auth` key)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this because I think the assumption is you'll be using the same username/password for your registry as your scoped registry.  Is there a reason you do not proxy npmjs.org through NXRM?  If so, I think you could use the same user/auth and it'd work.  That's the expected use case.

Comment: We had some issues with TTL and different versions of the same package using the Nexus proxy so were looking at this as an alternative.

Comment: @joedragons FYI - it turns out this is possible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

So, after some digging through the NPM source code, it turns out there is a way to do this.

My solution is below:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@test-scope:registry=http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/
//nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/:username=admin
//nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/:_password=YWRtaW4xMjM=
email=…
```

**Explanation:**

The scope `@test-scope` specifies that packages with the scope should be published to a different registry than the default `registry=` when executing the `npm publish` command.

The two lines starting with `//nexus:8081/...` are used to specify the credentials to the scoped repository for both `username` and `_password` where `_password` is the base64 encoded password component from the previously used `_auth` credentials.

Using this approach, only scoped packages will be published and installed from the private registry and all other packages will be installed from the default registry.

**Edit:**

Additional to this, the password can be specified as an environment variable so that it is not stored in plaintext in the file.

For example:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@test-scope:registry=http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/
//nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/:username=admin
//nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/:_password=${BASE64_PASSWORD}
email=…
```

Also, when using Nexus, the `email=` line must be specified.

Comment: see my answer for the standard way without storing plan test passsord

Comment: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/scopes?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)  clearly states to `append` not `prepend` the scope. Thankfully I found your answer

Comment: Finally something that helped get me over the line with Gitlab CICD when paired with Nexus!  
In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I set `npm config set 'nexusUrlHere/repository/npm-group/:_auth' "${NEXUS_TOKEN}"`, then I set NEXUS_TOKEN as a secret in Gitlab and then away we go :)

Answer (score 20):

for some strange reason the `_auth` is called `_authToken` when used with scoped packages. If you are using this you don't have to store your plain text password in your `.npmrc`

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@test-scope:registry=http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/ 
//nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-test/:_authToken=...
email=…
```

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command, replacing **@company-scope** with the scope, and **company-registry** with the name of your company’s npm Enterprise registry:

```
npm login --scope=@company-scope --registry=https://registry.company-registry.npme.io/
```

This information is available on the npm [documention](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-your-registry-settings-as-an-npm-enterprise-user#configuring-scopes-to-point-to-different-registries).